# Обфускация кода android-приложения

Tags: android, обфускация

Перед публикацией приложения возникла необходимость защитить код от кражи, поэтому хочется услышать Ваше мнение, как опытных программистов - как максимально обфусцировать код?

Добавил вот такие строчки в `build.gradle`:

```
     buildTypes {
          release {
               minifyEnabled true
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              signingConfig signingConfigs.config
          }
      }
```

Достаточно ли этого для защиты? Может есть более продвинутые способы и фишки?
Заранее - огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Вопрос хороший и интересный, но у меня есть встречный: а стоит ли? Содержит ли ваше приложение настолько уникальные и эффективные алгоритмы и логику, что кто-то захочет их "присвоить" путём декомпиляции и анализа вашего кода? И если да - стоит ли столь уникальную логику оставлять на стороне клиента? Ведь вне зависимости от того, насколько сильно вы запутаете код различными обфускаторами, он весь будет в руках клиента, и раскрытие ваших алгоритмов - лишь вопрос времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да этого достаточно. От целенаправленной декомпиляции не спасет, но замедлит. Из дополнительных фишек - хранить все пароли и ключи в зашифрованом виде.

Comment: Пароли, вы имеете ввиду, которые устанавливаются на ключ приложения?

Comment: Пароли и ключи от баз данных, серверов, сервисов, разных Amazon s3, итд.